# How to use the .bind(this) method the right way in Meteor js

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have a silly question (or not), how do we exactly or approximately use the bind method in Meteor?

I have the following code, but the fact I am repeating it bother's me.

Sank u very much for your opinions!

Bil

```
Meteor.publish('allComments', function() {

var comments = Comments.find();

comments.observeChanges({

  added: function (id, fields) {
    this.added('comments', id, fields);
  }.bind(this),

  changed: function (id, fields) {
    bind.changed('comments', id, fields);
  }.bind(this),

  removed: function (id) {
    this.removed('comments', id);
  }.bind(this)
 });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to Meteor but how Javascript works. In your js you are binding each function to the anonymous function given to `Meteor.publish`.

One way to do that:

```js
Meteor.publish('allComments', function() {

  var comments = Comments.find();

  var observer = {

    added: function (id, fields) {
      this.added('comments', id, fields);
    },

    changed: function (id, fields) {
      bind.changed('comments', id, fields);
    },

    removed: function (id) {
      this.removed('comments', id);
    }
   };

  observer.added = observer.added.bind(observer);
  observer.changed = observer.changed.bind(observer);
  observer.removed = observer.removed.bind(observer);

  comments.observeChanges(observer);

});
```

Comment: It's indeed a Javascript related "issue". However isn't there a better way to bind this in a more elegant way and avoiding the horrible _self = this_ ?

How about **Underscore's** _.bind ?

Comment: The _.bind is only for compat with older browsers, I don't know well Meteor but what you want to do is a bit strange since it's only when you pass a function as a params that you lose the context this of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You should use observeChanges.

Have a look to the documentation ([observeChanges](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-observeChanges))

Here is a quick example

```
Meteor.publish('orders', function(userId) {
  const fieldsIncluded = {
    fields: {
      _id: 1,
      idOrder: 1,
    },
  };

  Orders.find((userId), fieldsIncluded).observeChanges({
    added: (id, order) => {
      this.added('orders', id, formatOrderForGroom({ id, order }));
    },
    changed: (id) => {
      const fullOrder = Orders.findOne({ _id: id });

      this.changed('orders', id, formatOrderForGroom({ id, fullOrder }));
    },
    removed: (id) => {
      this.removed('orders', id);
    },
  });

  this.ready();
});
```